# Convergence rate of the moment generating function

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Let $S_n\sim Bin(n,p)$.
I would like to obtain an upper bound of
\begin{align}
\left|E\left[e^{h\frac{S_n-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}}\right]-e^{h^2/2}\right| \ (1)
\end{align}
(using $n,h,p$).
In my understanding,
$E\left[e^{h\frac{S_n-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}}\right]=e^{-h\frac{np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}}\left(1-p+pe^{\frac{h}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}}\right)^n$
converges to $e^{h^2/2}$ as $n\to \infty$ from the central limit theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\Delta=\left|E\left[e^{h\frac{S_n-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}}\right]-e^{\frac{h^2}{2}}\right| 
\end{align}$$

Continue the expansion using first logarithms and then Taylor series for large values of $n$ to make
$$E\left[e^{h\frac{S_n-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}}\right]=e^{\frac{h^2}{2}}+h^3\,e^{\frac{h^2}{2}}\frac{(1-2 p)}{6 \sqrt{(1-p) p}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to understand between the lines- where did you use the Taylor expansion? $e^{\frac{h}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}$?

Comment: @hiratat. I just worked the rhs of your last expression assuming that it is correct. Do not ask me more since I am very bad with probabilities. Cheers :-)